# intersection of an ellipsoid and cylindrical plane.

Tags: geometry, numerical-methods, computational-geometry, computational-mathematics

I need to understand if an ellipsoid and a cylindrical arc intersect, what will be the general equation of the cutted ellipse? How can I solve for that equation? I know in 3D, the equation of an cylinder is x^2+y^2=R^2, z=height and equation of an ellipsoid is (x^2)/(a^2)+(y^2)/(b^2)+(z^2)/(c^2)=1, a,b,c,z,R are known. Now if the ellipsoid intersect the cylindrical wall, how can I solve for the equation of the intersected ellipse? and I need the center of the intersected ellipse as well.I have no idea how to solve it! I will appreciate any help. Thank you very much.

**cylindrical are is a cylinder wall x2+y2=R2, with z height (this is the equation of a cylinder whose center is at (0,0,0).) 
**  in 3D, the ellipsoid will cut the plane in a circle (if b=c) or ellipse (if b not equal c). I need to solve this as I will use this concept for my numerical code to create an model.

Comment: This question _badly_ needs more context. As stated, it makes no sense: what is a "cylindrical plane", and why would you expect the intersection of a cylinder and an ellipsoid to be an ellipse? You tagged this as mathematical-physics; what is the application to physics here? Perhaps that would shed some light on what you are trying to do.

Comment: cylindrical plane is a cylinder wall x2+y2=R2, with z height (this is the equation of a cylinder whose center is at (0,0,0).)

Comment: in 3D, the ellipsoid will cut the plane in a circle (if b=c) or ellipse (if b not equal c). I need to solve this as I will use this concept for my numerical code to create an model.

Comment: Make up your mind: are you looking for intersection with a _plane_ or with a _cylinder_? Also, "numerical code" and "model" tell us nothing at all about _why_ you must use these particular two shapes or what they mean, so we cannot guess what it is you really want to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an idea - I don't know if it will fit your problem or not, cause actually you didn't describe it with sufficient level of details.

Let's think in terms of a cylindrical coordinate system - the equations below describe your cylindrical surface, ignoring that fact it has limited height (if I understood your question correctly).

$$x = R \cdot \sin(\phi), y = R \cdot \cos(\phi), z = z$$

Then you can substitute these $x$ and $y$ into the ellipsoid equation:

$$\frac {R^2} {a^2} \cdot \sin^2(\phi) + \frac {R^2}{b^2}\cdot \cos^2(\phi) + \frac{z^2}{c^2} = 1$$

You can express the $z$ as a function of $\phi$ - this will give you the intersection curve equation in cylindrical coordinates.

I hope it'll help.